# List.IndexOf returning -1 as a result

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, arraylist

So I have a function named "DisplayTextBlock" which displays TextBlock. I have made a list of this function, though whenever I try to find index of function in that List, I get -1.

```
    public void DisplayTextBlock(TextBlock block)
{
    Doing something here.        
}


int myActiveTextIndex;

    textDisplay.Add(() => DisplayTextBlock(block1 = new TextBlock("1. some text here")));
    textDisplay.Add(() => DisplayTextBlock(block2 = new TextBlock("2. some text here")));
    textDisplay.Add(() => DisplayTextBlock(block3 = new TextBlock("3.some text here")));
    textDisplay.Add(() => DisplayTextBlock(block4 = new TextBlock("4.some text here")));

List<Action> textDisplay = new List<Action>();


    myActiveTextIndex = textDisplay.IndexOf(() => DisplayTextBlock(block3));
```

Why does it output -1?

Comment: I never believe the result of Action or Func instance equality comparison. Even if they look same, they often result "not same".

Comment: These actions are NOT the same, because they do different things - the first assigns something to variable before calling the method, while the second is just  calling the method. Hence the compiler will generate 2 different methods for each `Action` delegate.

Comment: I think Ivan's comment has pointed the very problem, so deleted my own answer

Comment: Thank you Ivan and MyBug. Both of your helps are much appreciated, I see what I did wrong.

Comment: You made a new list at the end so eradicated the original ergo there’s nothing in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegates have this notion of equality, as stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.equals?view=netcore-3.1):

> The methods and targets are compared for equality as follows:
>
> If the two methods being compared are both static and are the same
> method on the same class, the methods are considered equal and the
> targets are also considered equal.
>
> If the two methods being compared are instance methods and are the
> same method on the same object, the methods are considered equal and
> the targets are also considered equal.
>
> Otherwise, the methods are not considered to be equal and the targets
> are also not considered to be equal.

You are using anonymous methods, like `() => DisplayTextBlock(block3)`, and even if anonymous method A is doing the same thing as anonymous method B (which is by the way not the case in your code) - they are still compiled into *different* methods. That means they will always violate `same method` in the comparision above, and are never equal.

If you want to store delegates in some kind of a list for later retrieval - don't rely on delegate equality comparision - use `Dictionary` and use appropriate key, by which you can retrieve associated delegate later.

Answer (score -1):

-1 means it cannot find the item in the list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I expect OP knows that, but doesn't know why their item isn't found.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why my item is not found in the list. I know I am doing something wrong somewhere but just couldn't figure it out.